# error reading X.509 key or certificate file

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, pem, swupdate, hawkbit

I'm setting **hawkBit** server and swupdate with SSL/TLS enabled (HTTPS). The steps are:

1. **Generate key**

   ```sh
   # Generate self signed root CA cert: ca.crt and ca.key
   openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -days 3650
   # Input the info with CN is <domain>

   # Generate server cert to be signed: server.csr and server.key
   openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -days 1095 -out server.csr
   # Input the info with CN is <domain>

   # Sign the server csr: server.crt
   openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 1095 -out server.crt

   # Create pkcs12: server.p12
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.p12 -inkey server.key -in server.crt
   # Enter Export Password:
   # Verifying - Enter Export Password:

   # import pkcs#12 to Java key store
   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
       -destkeystore server.jks -deststoretype pkcs12 \
       -alias 1 -deststorepass <pass> -srcstorepass <pass>
   ```
2. **Configure hawkBit**

   ```
   hawkbit.artifact.url.protocols.download-http.protocol=https
   hawkbit.artifact.url.protocols.download-http.port=<port>
   security.require-ssl=true
   server.use-forward-headers=true 

   server.ssl.key-store=/home/huong/software-update-server/hawkbit/hawkbit-runtime/hawkbit-update-server/jks/self_signed.p12
   server.ssl.key-store-password=<pass>
   server.ssl.key-password=<pass>
   server.ssl.enabled=true
   server.ssl.protocol=TLS
   server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
   ```

   At this time, I'm able to access hawkBit with https on browser.
3. **Configure swupdate**

- Enable: `CONFIG_CURL_SSL`, `CONFIG_DOWNLOAD_SSL`, `CONFIG_CHANNEL_CURL_SSL`, and `CONFIG_SURICATTA_SSL`
- Run command: `swupdate -v -k /etc/public.pem -f /suricatta.cfg -u ""`
- suricatta.cfg with suricatta section:

  ```
  suricatta :
  {
      tenant      = "DEFAULT";
      id          = "dev01";
      confirm     = 0;
      url         = "https://<domain>:<port>";
      polldelay   = 20;
      nocheckcert = false;
      retry       = 4;
      retrywait   = 200;
      loglevel    = 10;
      userid      = 1000;
      groupid     = 1000;
      cafile      = "/ca.crt";
      sslkey      = "/server.key";
      sslcert     = "/server.crt";
      gatewaytoken    = "<getway_token>";
      /*
      targettoken     = "3bc13b476cb3962a0c63a5c92beacfh7";
      */
  };
  ```

The log shows the error:

```
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running :  [channel_get] : Trying to GET https://<domain>:<port>/DEFAULT/controller/v1/dev01
*   Trying <ip_addr>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <domain> (<ip_addr>) port <port> (#0)
* found 1 certificates in /ca.crt
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* error reading X.509 key or certificate file
* Closing connection 0
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR corelib/channel_curl.c : channel_get : 1091 : Channel get operation failed (35): 'SSL connect error'
```

When running swupdate by the command: `swupdate -v -k /etc/public.pem  --ca-path="/chain.pem" -u '-t DEFAULT -u https://<domain>:<port> -i dev01 -g <getway_token>'`, with chain.pem is public key of server (archive by `openssl rsa -in server.key -pubout -out chain.pem`), or chain.pem is ca's public key or chain of the public key of ca and server, log shows the error:

```
[DEBUG] : SWUPDATE running :  [channel_get] : Trying to GET https://<domain>:<port>/DEFAULT/controller/v1/dev01
*   Trying <ip_addr>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <domain> (<ip_addr>) port <port> (#1)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
* Closing connection 1
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR corelib/channel_curl.c : channel_get : 1091 : Channel get operation failed (60): 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'
```

Please don't tell me to use server.crt or server.p12 or ca.crt as `--ca-path` because it shows the error:

```
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR corelib/swupdate_rsa_verify.c : load_pubkey : 52 : unable to load key filename /chain.pem
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR corelib/verify_signature.c : swupdate_dgst_init : 135 : Error loading pub key from /chain.pem
```

and I think `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY` can't get the public key from a certificate.

In hawkBit log, I don't found any weird log.

So please guide me to config swupdate to run with hawkBit with SSL/TLS enabled.

- Which certificate/key do I have to use on swupdate side?
- Should I use a config file instead of `--ca-path` argument?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your step "import pkcs#12 to Java key store" is strange, as the created file is again a PKCS#12 file because of `-deststoretype pkcs12`, just the file extension is `.jks`.

Comment: Hi @Robert, change to `-deststoretype JKS`, the result is the same.